# What is the canonical way to create streams of typescript flatbuffers?

Tags: javascript, typescript, flatbuffers

All the javascript/typescript flatbuffer test examples show only the simple case of creating one buffer at a time. What I want is to pack a whole series of buffers, all within the same `Uint8Array`. I want to avoid the expense of manually merging many Uint8Arrays.

Making them size-delimited would seem to be the answer. But I cannot see how to use the available APIs to achieve what I want.

E.g.

```
  // ~ = size prefix added by Monster.finishSizePrefixedMonsterBuffer()

  // What I want:       // What the APIs allow:

  ┌─UInt8Array──────┐   ┌─UInt8Array──────┐
  │~Monster         │   │~Monster         │
  │~Monster         │   ├─UInt8Array──────┤
  │~Monster         │   │~Monster         │
  │~Monster         │   ├─UInt8Array──────┤
  │...              │   │~Monster         │
  │~Monster         │   ├─UInt8Array──────┤
  └─────────────────┘   │~Monster         │
                        ├─UInt8Array──────┤
                        │~Monster         │
                        ├─────────────────┤
                        │...              │
                        ├─UInt8Array──────┤
                        │~Monster         │
                        └─────────────────┘
```

The docs specifically talk about using size-delimited flatbuffers to support streaming of flatbuffer objects. But is this not possible (without some hackery) using the javascript/typescript APIs? I tried this as well:

```
var offset = 0;
for (...) {
 Monster.startMonster(fbb);
 Monster.addName(fbb, name);
 ...
 offset = Monster.endMonster(fbb);
}
Monster.finishSizePrefixedMonsterBuffer(fbb, offset);

// Gives:

 ┌─UInt8Array──────┐
 │%Monster         │
 │ Monster         │
 │ Monster         │
 │ Monster         │
 │ ...             │
 │ Monster         │
 └─────────────────┘

// Where % is the size prefix and is the size total of ALL the 
// Monsters added. Not helpful for streaming because there is 
// no way to find the size of an individual Monster.
// The verify functions are not added by flatc for javascript.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I wonder if the answer is to change the schema to support an array of Monsters as the root.

Comment: The point of "streaming" usually is that you want to process elements incrementally / don't store them all in memory at once, so them sitting in individual arrays makes the most sense. If you can afford to keep them all in memory at once / serialize at once, then you should just put a "vector of elements" in your root table.

Comment: But streaming implies having a single contiguous buffer containing multiple objects one after the other. I expected there to be some mechanism to produce this result directly.

Comment: No, it most definitely does not imply "single contiguous buffer" :) In fact, the whole point of "streaming" is to avoid the need for that.

Comment: Think of sending this data over a socket connection or some other async I/O. At the socket level you want to be able to have a single source buffer and optimise the write chunk size completely independently of the actual flatbuffer message size depending on server load etc. A continuous (but finite obviously) source buffer is more efficient. This is a common pattern, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf. Aside from this I want to avoid the allocation and gc overhead of millions of UInt8Arrays.

Comment: hey, I am not a fan of allocations either, that's why I made FlatBuffers in the first place. But what you're talking about isn't typically called "streaming".